# Python performance: search large list vs sqlite

Tags: python, performance, sqlite

Lets say I have a database table which consists of three columns: `id`, `field1` and `field2`.  This table may have anywhere between 100 and 100,000 rows in it.  I have a python script that should insert 10-1,000 new rows into this table.  However, if the new `field1` already exists in the table, it should do an `UPDATE`, not an `INSERT`.

Which of the following approaches is more efficient?

1. Do a `SELECT field1 FROM table` (`field1` is unique) and store that in a list.  Then, for each new row, use `list.count()` to determine whether to `INSERT` or `UPDATE`
2. For each row, run two queries.  Firstly, `SELECT count(*) FROM table WHERE field1="foo"` then either the `INSERT` or `UPDATE`.

In other words, is it more efficient to perform n+1 queries and search a list, or 2n queries and get sqlite to search?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the need to `count` - what exactly are you counting? You just need to check existence, right? (Since there can only be one of each `field1` value..)

Comment: Good point, I suppose it could be simplified to `SELECT 1 FOM table WHERE field1="foo"`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, it seems like you could simply use SQLite's built in conflict handling mechanism.

Assuming you have a UNIQUE constraint on field1, you could simple use:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO table VALUES (...)
```

The following syntax is also supported (identical semantics):

```
REPLACE INTO table VALUES (...)
```

EDIT: I realise that I am not really answering your question, just providing an alternative solution which should be faster.

Comment: Great answer! Great functionality. A shame it's not in the SQL-92 specification, so that *all* RLDB's implement this :)

Comment: Thanks Nick, this is a good solution.  As with all good solutions, it has made me realise that I wasn't quite asking the right question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with sqlite but a general approach like this should work:

If there's a unique index on `field1` and you're trying to insert a value that's already there you should get an error. If insert fails, you go with the update.

Pseudocode:

```
try
{
    insert into table (value1, value2)
}
catch(insert fails)
{
    update table set field2=value2 where field1=value1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I imagine using a python dictionary would allow for much faster searching than using a python list. (Just set the values to 0, you won't need them, and hopefully a '0' stores compactly.)

As for the larger question, I'm curious too. :)

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be comparing apples with oranges.

A python list is only useful if your data fit into the address-space of the process. Once the data get big, this won't work any more.

Moreover, a python list is not indexed - for that you should use a dictionary.

Finally, a python list is non-persistent - it is forgotten when the process quits.

How can you possibly compare these?